# Finding $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$ in terms of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

Tags: calculus

> Finding $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$ in terms of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

**My Attempt:**

$\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}=\frac{d}{dy}(\frac{dx}{dy})=\frac d{dx}(\frac{dx}{dy})\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac d{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})^{-1}\frac{dx}{dy}=-(\frac{dy}{dx})^{-2}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\frac{dx}{dy}$

My doubt is in the step: $\frac{d}{dy}(\frac{dx}{dy})=\frac d{dx}(\frac{dx}{dy})\frac{dx}{dy}$

It's like I have broken the operator $\frac d{dy}$ into $\frac d{dx}\times\frac{dx}{dy}$. Is this valid? What can be the explanation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$If $y(x)$ admits an inverse $x(y)$ satisfying suitable conditions then $x'(t)=\frac{1}{y'(x(t))}$ from the chain rule applied to $y(x(t))=t$. I use a different letter $t$ for clarity. Then (derivative of a reciprocal): $$x''(t)=-\frac{y''(x(t))\cdot x'(t)}{(y'(x(t)))^2}=-\frac{y''(x(t))}{(y'(x(t)))^3}$$So in loose notation with $t=y$: $$\frac{\d^2 x}{\d y^2}=-\frac{\frac{\d^2y}{\d x^2}}{\left(\frac{\d y}{\d x}\right)^3}$$

An example with $y=x^2$ on the interval $\Bbb R_{\ge0}$:

> $\frac{\d y}{\d x}=2x$ and $\frac{\d^2 y}{\d x^2}=2$. The claim is then that: $$\frac{\d^2x}{\d y^2}=-\frac{2}{(2x)^3}=-\frac{1}{4x^3}$$We can check that $x=\sqrt{y}$ gives: $$\frac{\d^2x}{\d y^2}=\frac{\d x}{\d y}\left[\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\right]=-\frac{1}{4y\sqrt{y}}=-\frac{1}{4x^3}$$As claimed.

Another example with $y=\sin(x)$ on $[0,\pi/2]$:

> $\frac{\d y}{\d x}=\cos(x)$ and $\frac{\d^2y}{\d x^2}=-\sin(x)$. The claim is then that: $$\frac{\d^2x}{\d y^2}=-\frac{-\sin(x)}{\cos^3(x)}=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^3(x)}$$We can check that $x=\arcsin(y)$ (principal branch) gives: $$\begin{align}\frac{\d^2x}{\d y^2}&=\frac{\d x}{\d y}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right]\\&=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{-2y}{(1-y^2)\sqrt{1-y^2}}\\&=\frac{y}{(1-y^2)\sqrt{1-y^2}}\\&=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^3(x)}\end{align}$$As claimed.

With regards to your solution, it is difficult to parse. The Leibniz notation is what is used most often lower down the education system because it is easy to palm off as "fractions", but there is real danger in its overusage (you can never be sure if you did something because: "fractions!" or because your manipulation was valid ;)). Being careful with the functions at play will always be a safe approach.

Comment: To the aarbee, you can figure out the identity used for $x'(t)$ by considering  $f(x)=y,$ then $x = f^{-1}(y),$ and so we can use implicit differentiation to arrive at $\frac{dx}{dx} = \frac{df^{-1}(y)}{dx}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx},$ giving $\frac{dx}{dy} =  \frac{df^{-1}(y)}{dx}.$

Comment: Thankyou very much

Comment: @aarbee You're welcome. I hope the examples are clear

Comment: It took me time to understand the notations in the first para. But now things are clear. Thanks.

Comment: While I broadly agree with the sentiment towards the dangers of fractional notation, it can be very helpful if you use it properly, and it can even be made rigorous. The main dangers lie with higher order derivatives as Leibniz notation is just wrong for those, and also when working with partial derivatives as those can make things more complicated.